# Audio working on some iPhones but not on others

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm having a very strange issue with audio in iOS. My app uses a basic implementation of AVSpeechSynthesizer to read out some text. The code looks like this:

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:string];
utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate;
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"en-GB"];
[synth speakUtterance:utterance];
```

This works in the simulator and it works on my iPhone SE. However, on some other iPhones it doesn't work.

I have tried it on two different iPhone 6S's. It works on one of them but not on the other. I tried it on an iPhone 6 Plus and it works. So of four iPhones I've tried, it works on two and doesn't work on the other two.

All iPhones are running some version of iOS 10, but whether 10.0.1 or 10.0.2 or 10.1 doesn't appear to make any difference.

Of course on the ones that don't play the sound, I have checked that volume is up , not muted, and that other apps will produce sound as normal.

This is unlike any bug I've ever encountered, and I'm afraid I have no idea how to even begin troubleshooting it.

Comment: maybe the phones were muted?

Comment: I stated in my question that this has been checked and is not the case.